# How to change endpoint binding type when dynamic hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

i have 2 web.config. one of them is inside of the client, the other is inside of the server.

if i call service from client. below error occurs:
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:55876/ServiceWithoutSVC/WelcomeService.svc?wsdl.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

I GUESS CLIENT HAS wsHttpBinding BUT SERVER BASICHTTPBINDING. How can i change relativeadress binding as wshttpbinding inserver web config?

[image]

client Web config :

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding" allowCookies="true"  maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint name="BookService"
              address="http://localhost:55876/ServiceWithoutSVC/WelcomeService.svc?wsdl"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="IsoletedClient.Services.IWelcomeService" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" />

</client>
```

server web.config:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
   relativeAddress="./ServiceWithoutSVC/WelcomeService.svc"
    service="ServiceWithoutSVC.WelcomeService" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```